# Не могу удалить пакет из npm

Tags: npm

Привет. Почему-то не могу удалить два пакета из npm:

```
"jsdom": "^11.0.0",
"requirejs": "^2.3.3"
```

Использую команду `npm uninstall -g jsdom --save`, но из `package.json` они не удаляются.

Answer (score 1):

Вот так удаляется    `npm uninstall jsdom --save`

Answer (score 0):

это просто:

- тег `-g` оперирует с пакетом зависимостей в глобальной среде (устанавливает/удаляет пакет глобально в вашу **FS**, а не в проект). после этого пакет зависимостей доступен всегда и везде на Вашем ПК.
- без тега `-g`, по-умолчанию, пакет регистрируется в Ваш проект (в файл `package.json`) и устанавливается тоже в проекте (в `node_modules`)

Comment: и вообще странно, что вопрос всплыл спустя **1,5 года**..